# Как убрать редирект в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, modx, редирект

День добрый! 
Есть два домена, один в зоне .ru другой в .com. Хочется что бы домен в зоне .com стал основным. Но сейчас сайт настроен так что с него идет редирект на английскую версию сайта в зоне .ru. Уже перековыряла весь интернет и весь .htaccess файл, вплоть до того что полностью его переписала. Не помогает. В чем подвох? Может быть редирект настроен еще где-то? Или все-таки я не правильно правлю код?

```
# Friendly URLs
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule $ http://yandex.ru/ [R=301,L]
# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://store.ru/en/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect from mydomain.com/rootname to mydomain.com/rootname/
RewriteRule ^en$ en/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ru$ ru/ [R=301,L]


# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ru/(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
#Action php5.3-script  /cgi-bin/php5.3.cgi
#AddType php5.3-script .php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'text/html; charset=utf-8' .html .htm .shtml
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вот ваш редирект

```
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*) http://store.ru/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Если вы уберете не будет редиректа

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! Делала на самом деле тоже самое все, но видимо в кэш застряла старая версия :)